# Firestore how stop Transaction?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In transaction I only want to write data if data not present

```
DocumentReference callConnectionRef1 = firestore.collection("connectedCalls").document(callChannelModel.getUid());

  firestore.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function < Void > () {
 @Override
 public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(callConnectionRef1);

   Log.d(TAG, callChannelModel.getUid());


  if (!snapshot.exists()) {
   //my code
   transaction.set(callConnectionRef1, model);
  } else {
   //do nothing   
  }
  return null;

 });
```

You can see in my Document reference is uid based and in my log I am printing uid

So where uid's data not exist my Log prints only once and I call transaction.set() elsewhere it keep showing Log of uid where data exists already it looks like my transaction keep running if I don't call transaction.set()

How can I stop it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "keeps running"? Does `runTransaction` just not return at all?

Comment: I added logs of transaction starting......it keep showing that log

Comment: Please could you give more details in the question? It's not clear to me what you mean at the moment. If you could provide a [mcve] that would be very helpful.

Comment: I edited my question...Please take a look

Comment: My *guess* is that an exception is happening separately. Again, if you could edit your question into a [mcve] which would make it easy for someone to reproduce the problem, that would really help. (The example should do nothing *but* demonstrate the problem.)

Comment: Same happens with me on Android. The transaction keeps trying to apply itself (the `apply()` function keeps getting called), even after throwing an exception. For me it performs 5 tries, and only then `onFailure()` function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example given in the documentation, just throw an exception and it will exit the transaction and stop executing.

```
db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Double>() {
    @Override
    public Double apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(sfDocRef);
        double newPopulation = snapshot.getDouble("population") + 1;
        if (newPopulation <= 1000000) {
            transaction.update(sfDocRef, "population", newPopulation);
            return newPopulation;
        } else {
            throw new FirebaseFirestoreException("Population too high",
                    FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.ABORTED);
        }
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Double>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Double result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success: " + result);
    }
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
    }
});
DocSnippets.java
```

Comment: This example kind of not working since the transaction tried for like 5 times on Android.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me too on Android. The transaction performs 5 attempts to apply itself, and only then the `onFailure()` function is called (even if you throw an exception in the `apply()` function).

But looks like this is the expected behavior:

1. See here: https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/transaction.html
   Notice `MAX_ATTEMPTS` defaults to 5.
2. In this github issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/520 there's a request to add a "number of retries" option.