# Android: How to stop a Firestore transaction?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

First I am querying some documents in the Firestore using this `queryWaitingRoom()` and calling the `runTransactionInWaitingRoom()` if the result satisfies the condition.

Here's the first function:

```
private fun queryWaitingRoom() {
    waitingRoomRef
        .orderBy("isAvailable", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

            if (!documents.isEmpty){
                for (document in documents) {
                    val waitingRoomId = document.get("id").toString()

                    runTransactionInWaitingRoom(waitingRoomId)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

My question is, in `runTransactionInWaitingRoom()` if the value `currentState` doesn't equal to `true`, how can i stop the `transaction` right in the `else` block? and call the `queryWaitingRoom()` again?
Here's the second function:

```
 private fun runTransactionInWaitingRoom(waitingRoomId: String){
    val docRef = waitingRoomRef.document(waitingRoomId)

    db.runTransaction { transaction ->

        val snapshot = transaction.get(docRef)
        val currentState = snapshot.getBoolean("isAvailable")

        if (currentState == true){
            transaction.update(docRef, "isAvailable", false)
        } else {
            ///// STOP THE TRANSACTION RIGHT HERE /////
            ///// And call the the queryWaitingRoom() again /////

            Log.d("OIWENCLKSJF", "Transaction.currentState != true")   // getting called 5 or 6 times.

            throw FirebaseFirestoreException("Population too high",    // only get called at the last attemp.
                FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.ABORTED)
        }

    }.addOnSuccessListener {

    }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Log.w("OIWENCLKSJF", "Transaction failure.", e)
    }
}
```

What I have got so far is that the `transaction` keeps calling itself even if I am throwing the `exception` in the `else` block.
I got a similar question right here in SO but it didn't help. I will really appreciate it if someone can guide me a little bit.

> [Firestore how stop Transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735358/firestore-how-stop-transaction)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, is `isAvailable` property apart of the same document as it is the `id`?

Comment: I don't think database structure has anything to do with this problem. And yes the `isAvailable` property is from the same document. Also `isAvailable` can only have two values..`true` and `false`. It gets the value of  `true` when first created.

Answer (score 1):

> And yes the isAvailable property is from the same document.

If both properties are apart of the same document, then run the transaction only if the `isAvailable` property holds the value of true:

```
if (!documents.isEmpty){
    for (document in documents) {
        val waitingRoomId = document.get("id").toString()
        val isAvailable = document.getBoolean("isAvailable")
        if(isAvailable) {
            runTransactionInWaitingRoom(waitingRoomId)
        }
    }
}
```

The idea behind this solution is to run the transaction **only** when `isAvailable` is true. What you are doing now, you are always running the transaction, and inside it, if the condition isn't true, cancel the transaction. Why this solution is not feasible? Imagine you have 1 MIL documents, and only 1 of them has `isAvailable` true, are you willing to run 1 MIL transactions for the sake of one document? I'm afraid you're not. Remember that in Firestore, every document read that is performed, costs one read operation.

A solution that's even better, is to query the database directly for the documents in which the `isAvailable` property holds the value of true:

```
waitingRoomRef
    .whereEqualTo("isAvailable", true) //Added
    .orderBy("isAvailable", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .limit(1)
    .get()
```

In this case, you'll directly get the desired documents. The cost of this operation will be equal to the number of documents that the query returns.

Comment: I should have explained it in more details but this will not work in my case even if i use  `.orderBy("isAvailable", true)` . Because in the time of updating the `isAvailable = false` someone might change its value to `false` already. Then i will run into the same problem again

Comment: This is the part of  a matchmaking system. When i update the documet's `isAvailable` field to `false` that means i have connected with the document's creator.

Comment: Makes sense. In that case, you should use a [real-time listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), meaning that you'll be notified as the change happens and then you can take some action. You'll always be in sync with Firestore servers.

Comment: i have used the realtime listeners in other parts of this system but in this case i need to read and update the value of `isAvailable` to `false` using `transaction` because many users may get the same document and trying to change its value to `false` at the same moment. So i have to make sure only one can change it. Which is i am doing right in the `runTransaction..()` function but i haven't found way to stop the `transaction` and to re-run the `qurying` again, when the value of `isAvailable` has already changed to `false` by someone else .

Comment: If the value of `isAvailable` can be changed also from other parts of your application, then using the transaction here and in the other part is correct. You cannot have inconsistent data whatsoever. So there is no need to re-run the query or stop the transaction, simply use the logic in my answer.

Comment: I do need to run the query again at least for a minute, because i have to make sure that the user gets connect with some other user. That's the whole point of this matchmaking system.

Comment: The second solution provided by @AlexMamo is the best way to do it, as mentioned you're retrieving documents that you're not going to use (which you will be billed for). You can create some kind of queue that listens to real time changes and enqueue a batch if needed, don't worry Firestore updates are so fast that it will finish before the user can notice it. With your solution about interrupting transactions you could find yourself without finishing a single one if your user switches constantly between rooms.